# Check if after a particular timestamp , response is different

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a response that has result in following way :

```
timestamp   errorType  

t1           success
t2           fail
t3           success
t4           fail
t5           fail
t6           success
t7           success
```

What i want to do is catch a scenario where say after a particular time , all request are failing , this case can be shown as :

```
t1           success
t2           success
t3           success
t4           fail
t5           fail
t6           fail
t7           fail
```

So here i would want to catch the particular starting time-stamp after which all response/error are failures  What approach i can follow . TIA

================

As of now , what i could think of is to iterate and store the SuccessLatest timestamp and FailureEarliest timestamp , so if SuccessLatest < FailureEarliest  , we could have a concrete decision that is failing completely after certain time . Any suggestions are welcome .

Comment: This problem is not well-defined. Assuming that we are handling a stream of event, so right after t2, we should raise an alarm that saying the requests are failing, then t3 -> alarm is off, then at t4 and t5 -> raising alarm. The usual approach is based on a sliding window and the percentage of error rate in that sliding window.

Comment: thanks for your input , but first table is just for example , i actually need to handle second case table

Comment: You receive all events at once, or as a stream of event?

Comment: got all at once

Comment: I see, so, this should be easy, just iterating the events backward right? if list of event ends with fail, just following the failing series until switch to sucess.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to just..

> catch the particular starting time-stamp after which all response/error are failures

..then this can be done with sql in following way:

```
SELECT max(timestamp)
  FROM [Results] r1 where r1.errortype= 'success'
```

If you do not have sql-context and data is just as an timestamp-ordered array in memory, you can get it following way (pseudo-code):

```
var answer = null
loop array items backwards from newest to oldest
  if(item.errortype == success)
  {
     answer = item.timestamp
     break loop
  }
```

If none of these answer matches your requirements, just make a comment so I can elaborate my answer.